# Custom floating action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Help me please. 
How can i do fab like this.
What i must use, that i can do this.
Maybe you know, that i can read about my problem?

Are there any samples / examples to perform such a transformation?

I tried using a background, but it's doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem in making this view.

- FloatingActionButton hides all view on it. So your dot view can not be placed upon FAB. So we have to make ImageView instead of FAB.

Put this in your layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_circle"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:src="@drawable/red_circle" />

</FrameLayout>
```

make new xml in `res>drawable>blue_circle_gradient.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#8e81fc"
        android:startColor="#7264EA" />
</shape>
```

make new xml in `res>drawable>red_circle.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

Output will be same like this:

[image]

Comment: why you have a elevation, but in my lauout i didn't see him

Comment: I just your image to show you output, but there will not be elevation.

Comment: Can you help me please, how can i do elevation like in photo?